# ¿como puedo agregar gastos y cantidad a una lista creada en Html por medio de un boton con condigo js?

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero ingresar un gasto y su cantidad por medio de dos caja de texto y agregarlo a una lista, pero no me permite agregarlo a lista, tampoco me tira errores.
recien estoy arrancando con java script

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="prueba1">
      <h1>Añade tus gastos aqui</h1>
        <input type="text" id="NombreGasto">
        <input type="text" id="Cantidad">
        <input type="button" value="Agregar">
    </div>

<div class="prueba2">
    <h2>Listado</h2>
    <div class="control">
        <ul class="lista" id="lista">
            <li>prueba</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <label for="pre">Presupuesto:</label>
    <label for="res">Restante:</label>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Con este codigo intento capturar lo que entra por la caja de texto y añardirlo a una lista pero no funciona

```
    let presupuesto=prompt('íngrese su presupuesto'),
    lista=document.getElementById('lista'),
    gastos=document.getElementById('gastos'),
    cantidad=document.getElementById('cantidad'),
    btnNuevoGasto=document.getElementById('btn-agregar');
    
    
    function agregar() {
        let nombreGasto=gastos.value,
            elementoGasto=document.createElement('li'),
            contenidoGasto=document.createTextNode(nombreGasto);
    
            elementoGasto.appendChild(contenidoGasto);
            lista.appendChild(elementoGasto);
        
    }
    
    btnNuevoGasto.addEventListener('click', agregar);
```

Comment: El código va como texto

Comment: Deberias de agregar el codigo como text, en vez de imagenes. Asi sera mas facil ayudarte.

Comment: gracias, me daba errores y no entiendo como arregralo

Comment: Deberías de añadir el código que llevas en Javascript, con el HTML no se puede hacer mucho. ://

Comment: gracias, le saque la parte html porque me dice que es mucho codigo, gracias

Comment: El evento es `click` en minuscula todo. Tú has puesto `Click` y creo que por eso no te funciona prueba `btnNuevoGasto.addEventListener('click', agregar);`

Comment: lo cambie como me dijiste y no funciona

Comment: Todos tus IDs son incorrectos, por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el HTML, de ahí viene el error. Si te dice que es mucho código, agrega una explicación al final de la pregunta.